# Un programa funciona en Ubuntu 64-bits pero no en Ubuntu 32-bits

Tags: c, ubuntu

Estoy haciendo un código en Ubuntu que, de momento, lee los valores de un fichero, los almacena en una lista doblemente enlazada implementada con una pila y calcula las medias y desviaciones típicas de las columnas de ese fichero. Estaba programándolo en Ubuntu 64-bits y no me da ningún fallo. Hoy me he enterado de que este código que estoy haciendo (es un código para una práctica que me piden en la Universidad) se me va a evaluar en Ubuntu 32-bits. He copiado el código tal cual de mi máquina Ubuntu 64-bits a la de Ubuntu 32-bits. Al ejecutarlo en la máquina de 32-bits me salta un error por consola sobre los malloc (cosa que no me pasaba en el Ubuntu 64-bits). Este es el código:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <math.h>
#define MAX 256 

typedef struct Datos{
    int filaCorrespondiente;
    int columnaCorrespondiente;
    char *valorCorrespondiente;
    char *tipoCorrespondiente;
} datos;

typedef struct Nodo{
    struct Nodo *anterior;
    datos d;
    struct Nodo *siguiente;
} nodo;

nodo *crearNodo(datos d);
nodo * insertar(nodo *cima, nodo *nuevoNodo);
void listar(nodo *cima);
void visualizarColumna(nodo *cima, int i);
char *devolverTipo(nodo *cima, int i);
double calcularMedias(nodo *cima, int i, int numFilasTotal);
double calcularDesviaciones(nodo *cima, int i, int numFilasTotal, double media);


int main(){

    nodo *cima = NULL;
    datos d;
    FILE *f = NULL;
    f = fopen("BreastTissueTrain.csv", "r");
    int filaActual=1, columnaActual=1, i=3;
    char linea[MAX];
    double media=0, desviacion=0;
    char *tipoActual;
    int numFilasTotal, numColumnasTotal;

    printf("\n---CONTENIDO DEL FICHERO---\n\n");
    if(f){
            fgets(linea, MAX, f);
            while(!feof(f)){
            char *token = strtok(linea, ",");
            char *tipo;
            while(token!=NULL){
                printf("%s ", token);
                d.valorCorrespondiente = token;
                d.filaCorrespondiente = filaActual;
                d.columnaCorrespondiente = columnaActual;

                /*numFilasTotal se actualizará cada vez que se pase
                por este bucle, de tal forma que en la última pasada
                adquirirá el valor máximo de la fila (que equivale al
                número de filas total). Análogamente se hace esto con
                la variable numColumnasTotal*/
                numFilasTotal = filaActual;
                numColumnasTotal = columnaActual;

                switch(d.columnaCorrespondiente){
                    case 1:
                        d.tipoCorrespondiente = "Case";
                        break;
                    case 2:
                        d.tipoCorrespondiente = "Class";
                        break;
                    case 3:
                        d.tipoCorrespondiente = "I0";
                        break;
                    case 4:
                        d.tipoCorrespondiente = "PA500";
                        break;
                    case 5:
                        d.tipoCorrespondiente = "HFS";
                        break;
                    case 6:
                        d.tipoCorrespondiente = "DA";
                        break;
                    case 7:
                        d.tipoCorrespondiente = "Area";
                        break;
                    case 8:
                        d.tipoCorrespondiente = "A/DA";
                        break;
                    case 9:
                        d.tipoCorrespondiente = "Max IP";
                        break;
                    case 10:
                        d.tipoCorrespondiente = "DR";
                        break;
                    case 11:
                        d.tipoCorrespondiente = "P";
                        break;
                }
                cima = insertar(cima, crearNodo(d));
                columnaActual++;
                token = strtok(NULL, ",");
            }
            fgets(linea, MAX, f);
            filaActual++;
            columnaActual=1;
        }
        }else{
        printf("\nERROR! Revisa que el fichero BreastTissueTrain.csv está en la misma carpeta desde la cual estás ejecutando este programa\n\n");
        return 0;
    }
    printf("\n\n\n");
        fclose(f);

    printf("---ALMACENAMIENTO DE CADA VALOR EN UN NODO---\n");
    listar(cima);


    printf("\n\n\n---MEDIAS Y DESVIACIONES---\n\n");
    printf("La columna 1 del fichero corresponde a los case y la columna 2 a las class.\n");

    for(i=3; i<=numColumnasTotal; i++){ //Se deben tomar los datos a partir de la columna tres hasta el final
        printf("\n\nColumna numero %d ", i);
        tipoActual = devolverTipo(cima, i);
        printf(" (de tipo %s): ", tipoActual);

        printf("\n\nValores: ");
        visualizarColumna(cima, i);

        printf("\nLa media de la columna %d es: ", i);
        media = calcularMedias(cima, i, numFilasTotal);
        printf("%lf", media);

        printf("\nLa desviacion de la columna %d es: ", i);
        desviacion = calcularDesviaciones(cima, i, numFilasTotal, media);
        printf("%lf", desviacion);
    }

    printf("\n\n");
    return 0;
}

nodo *crearNodo(datos d){
    nodo *nuevoNodo=(nodo *)malloc(sizeof(nodo));

    nuevoNodo->d.filaCorrespondiente = d.filaCorrespondiente;
    nuevoNodo->d.columnaCorrespondiente = d.columnaCorrespondiente;
    nuevoNodo->d.valorCorrespondiente = (char *) malloc(sizeof(d.valorCorrespondiente));
    strcpy(nuevoNodo->d.valorCorrespondiente, d.valorCorrespondiente);
    nuevoNodo->d.tipoCorrespondiente = (char *) malloc(sizeof(d.tipoCorrespondiente));
    strcpy(nuevoNodo->d.tipoCorrespondiente, d.tipoCorrespondiente);

    nuevoNodo->anterior = NULL;
    nuevoNodo->siguiente = NULL;
    return nuevoNodo;
}

nodo *insertar(nodo *cima, nodo *nuevoNodo){
    if(cima==NULL){
        cima=nuevoNodo;
    }else{
        nuevoNodo->siguiente=cima;
        cima->anterior=nuevoNodo;
        cima=nuevoNodo;
    }
    return cima;
}

void listar(nodo *cima){
    nodo *actual, *limite;
    if(cima==NULL){
        printf("La pila esta vacia");
    }else{
        /*Tengo que hacer este for previo en este y en varios métodos
        más debido a que, al haber implementado mi código mediante una
        pila con doble enlace, se me imprimirían todos los valores del
        final al principio (este primer for a continuación los invierte,
        así que ya irían del principio al final, tal como sería normal verlo) */

        for(actual=cima; actual!=NULL; actual=actual->siguiente){
            if(actual!=NULL){
                limite = actual;
            }
        }

        for(actual=limite; actual!=NULL; actual=actual->anterior){
            printf("\n\nValor: %s", actual->d.valorCorrespondiente);
            printf(" Fila: %d", actual->d.filaCorrespondiente);
            printf(" Columna: %d", actual->d.columnaCorrespondiente);
            printf(" Tipo: %s\n", actual->d.tipoCorrespondiente);
        }
    }
}

void visualizarColumna(nodo *cima, int i){
    nodo *actual, *limite;

    for(actual=cima; actual!=NULL; actual=actual->siguiente){
        if(actual!=NULL){
            limite = actual;
        }
    }

    for(actual=limite; actual!=NULL; actual=actual->anterior){
        if(actual->d.columnaCorrespondiente == i){
            printf("%s ", actual->d.valorCorrespondiente);
        }
    }
}

char *devolverTipo(nodo *cima, int i){
    nodo *actual, *limite;
    char *tipoActual;

    for(actual=cima; actual!=NULL; actual=actual->siguiente){
        if(actual!=NULL){
            limite = actual;
        }
    }

    for(actual=limite; actual!=NULL; actual=actual->anterior){
        if(actual->d.columnaCorrespondiente == i){
            tipoActual = actual->d.tipoCorrespondiente;
            goto TIPOENCONTRADO;    /*De esta forma evitamos que se asigne tipoActual repetidas veces,
                        cuando con una sola basta, saliendo de ambos bucles*/
        }
    }

    TIPOENCONTRADO:
    return tipoActual;
}

double calcularMedias(nodo *cima, int i, int numFilasTotal){
    nodo *actual, *limite;
    double sumaValores=0;
    int numValores = numFilasTotal;
    double media;
    double valorParseado;
    char *ptr;

    for(actual=cima; actual!=NULL; actual=actual->siguiente){
        if(actual!=NULL){
            limite = actual;
        }
    }

    for(actual=limite; actual!=NULL; actual=actual->anterior){
        if(actual->d.columnaCorrespondiente == i){
            valorParseado = strtod(actual->d.valorCorrespondiente, &ptr);
            sumaValores = sumaValores + valorParseado;
        }
    }

    media = sumaValores / numValores;
    return media;
}

double calcularDesviaciones(nodo *cima, int i, int numFilasTotal, double media){
    nodo *actual, *limite;  
    double desviacion=0;
    double valorParseado=0;
    int numValores = numFilasTotal;
    double tmp1=0, tmp2=0;
    char *ptr;

    //Fórmula: RaízCuadrada(Sumatorio((xi-media)^2)/(N-1))

    for(actual=cima; actual!=NULL; actual=actual->siguiente){
        if(actual!=NULL){
            limite = actual;
        }
    }

    for(actual=limite; actual!=NULL; actual=actual->anterior){
        if(actual->d.columnaCorrespondiente == i){
            valorParseado = strtod(actual->d.valorCorrespondiente, &ptr);
            tmp1 = valorParseado - media; //Xi - Media
            tmp1 = pow(tmp1, 2); //Elevar al cuadrado lo anterior
            tmp2 = tmp2 + tmp1; //Sumatorio de lo anterior
        }
    }

    numValores = numValores - 1; //Número de filas menos 1
    desviacion = tmp2 / numValores; //Hacemos la división
    desviacion = sqrt(desviacion); //Y finalmente haciendo la raíz cuadrada tenemos la desviación

    return desviacion;
}
```

Este es el fichero que se necesita en la carpeta del ejecutable para que funcione: https://drive.google.com/open?id=1unMDSfTHtanoei5rURXxlNZ-LFsQIVhy

Estas son las capturas de pantalla de lo que me sale al ejecutar el programa en Ubuntu 64-bits (no me da fallos): https://drive.google.com/file/d/1cAN4mtFZSjQJ-vNmVV6o77WqeGSTIogr/view?usp=sharing

Y esta es la captura de pantalla de lo que me sale al ejecutar el programa en Ubuntu 32-bits (me da fallo de sysmalloc): https://drive.google.com/file/d/17rzgX-puN0dkpaNZZH9jEseMH74Qf7Uq/view?usp=sharing

Creo que esto sucede porque mi programa usa demasiada memoria para un Ubuntu de 32-bits. ¿Alguna idea para solucionarlo?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En `crearNodo` tienes:

```
nuevoNodo->d.valorCorrespondiente = (char *) malloc(sizeof(d.valorCorrespondiente));
strcpy(nuevoNodo->d.valorCorrespondiente, d.valorCorrespondiente);
```

Como `d.valorCorrespondiente` es de tipo `char *` (puntero a char), al aplicarle
el operador `sizeof` devuelve el tamaño de un puntero y no el tamaño de la cadena.
Entonces, si la cadena es muy larga `strcpy` escribe donde no le corresponde y
corrompe memoria. Para reservar la cantidad de memoria necesaria para la cadena,
debes calcular la longitud de la cadena con `strlen` y sumarle 1 para dejar espacio
para el caracter núlo. Corregido sería así:

```
nuevoNodo->d.valorCorrespondiente = (char *) malloc(strlen(d.valorCorrespondiente) + 1);
```

Comment: Funcionó perfectamente. He hecho lo mismo con d.tipoCorrespondiente y ya me funciona en el Ubuntu de 32 bits. Gracias